# What is the difference between getDefaultInstance() and getInstance() in Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm

What is the difference between `realm.getDefaultInstance()` and `realm.getInstance(context)`? In general, when will you choose one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getDefaultInstance()` method instantiates the Realm with a **default** `RealmConfiguration`.

`getInstance(RealmConfiguration configuration)` return instance with your configuration for example database `name`, `schemaVersion`, `migration`, some of them are necessary in real world apps especially with Realm platform synchronization.

But in case you are using `getDefaultInstance()` in many places in your app, to avoid calling configuration every time you can use `setDefaultConfiguration(RealmConfiguration)` and then `getDefaultInstance()` will always return Realm instance with your configuration.

Comment: So what i understood is that by writing(please correct my if i'm wrong):- `RealmConfiguration config = new` `RealmConfig.Builder().name("myrealm.realm").build();` `setDefaultConfiguration(config);` 
`Realm db = getDefaultInstance();` 
this will happen:- 
1. `setDefaultConfiguration(config)` will create a new realm file named myrealm.realm by using the configuration provided by me.
2. an object that represent the file will be created and returned to me.

Comment: setDefaultConfiguration(config); will only set your configuration as default, the Realm db will be created or returned existing Realm when you call getInstance

Comment: So the first time i call `getDefaultInstance()` then the Realm db "myrealm.realm" will be created first and then returned. But if i call `getDefaultInstance()` 2nd or 3rd time, then it will not create a new Realm db but only return the existing one i.e "myrealm.realm".

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html):

> **getDefaultInstance()**
>   Realm static constructor that returns the Realm instance defined by
>   the RealmConfiguration set by
>   setDefaultConfiguration(RealmConfiguration)

So it's using the default configuration. As oppposed to `getInstance(RealmConfiguration configuration)`, which you can provide your own realm configuration.